# Java applet resetting all cookies?

Tags: java, applet

I'm running a third party java applet called 'ptviewer':
http://www.fsoft.it/panorama/ptviewer.htm

It's running in a site built with the Codeigniter PHP framework. Everytime I visit a page where the applet is included, all my cookies are mysteriously removed from the browser.

I have narrowed the problem down to the applet. Comment it out and everything is fine.

Is there any known 'feature' of the Java plugin which causes cookies to be removed?

Problem occurs in: FF(3.x), IE8, Chrome

Comment: Definitely not the Java plugin, I'd suspect your specific applet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Piskvor assured me that it was something to do with the applet itself, I opened up the source code for ptviewer and discovered that it sends its own user-agent in the header.
CodeIgniter's session library (1.7.2) does a security check to make sure the user-agent matches. Commenting out lines 185-189 in Session.php solves this problem.

Comment: Mmm, must be something from the 2.8 version. I'll take note. Thanks Chris!

Answer (score 0):

In /application/config/config.php, set sess_match_useragent to FALSE

```
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

Work fine in Codeigniter 2.1.4.

Thank you very much!